# Diferença entre select a. ou b

Tags: sql, oracle

Qual é a diferença de fazer a pesquisa por select a. ou b.?

Exemplo:

```
select --a.num_duplicata,a.data_prorrogacao,a.seq_duplicatas,
        a.cli_dup_cgc_cli9 as cgc9,a.cli_dup_cgc_cli4 as cgc4,a.cli_dup_cgc_cli2 as cgc2,b.nome_cliente as cliente,
        sum(a.saldo_duplicata) as saldo_vencer
        --a.saldo_duplicata
from fatu_070 a, pedi_010 b
where a.codigo_empresa > 0
      and a.cli_dup_cgc_cli9 = b.cgc_9
      and a.cli_dup_cgc_cli4 = b.cgc_4
      and a.cli_dup_cgc_cli2 = b.cgc_2
      and (b.grupo_economico = &gru or b.grupo_economico = &gru2)
      and a.data_prorrogacao >= current_date - 1
      --and b.nome_cliente like 'naya je%'
      --and a.num_duplicata = 77486
group by a.cli_dup_cgc_cli9, a.cli_dup_cgc_cli4, a.cli_dup_cgc_cli2, b.nome_cliente
order by a.cli_dup_cgc_cli9, a.cli_dup_cgc_cli4, a.cli_dup_cgc_cli2, b.nome_cliente
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi a pergunta mas no caso "a" e "b" são aliases (apelidos) assim se refere a a.data_prorrogacao no lugar de fatu_070.data_prorrogacao

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suponhamos o exemplo queiramos listar o nome do Funcionario e o seu respectivo Cargo:

```
SELECT f.nome, d.cargo
FROM Funcionario f 
INNER JOIN Departamento d
ON F.IdCargo = D.IdCargo
```

Obserse que usei a letra **'f'** para referenciar as colunas da tabela *Funcionário*, e a letra **'d'** para referenciar as colunas da tabela *Departamento*. Ou seja, fiz nada mais na menos do que **APELIDAR** as tabelas para que o código *SQL* não ficasse extenso.
Esse código abaixo obteria o mesmo resultado sem o uso dos apelidos, no qual chamamos de ***'alias'***. Ficaria assim

```
SELECT Funcionario.nome, Departamento.cargo
FROM Funcionario 
INNER JOIN Departamento
ON Funcionario.IdCargo = Departamento.IdCargo
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: @AndersondeFreitasMigloranza se a resposta te ajudou, por favor, marca como respondida.